# accessing array members using reflection

Tags: .net, arrays, visual-studio, reflection, c++-cli

It is possible access array elements using Reflection?

For example if i have the array

```
array<String^>^ Strings_Array=gcnew array<String^>{"One","Two","Three"};
```

And the function

```
Replace_Two(Object^ Strings_Array)
{
 Type^ Array_Type=Strings_Array->GetType();

 String^ Array_Type_Name=Array_Type->ToString(); //it is "System.ValueType[]"

 //make magic to replace "Two" to "Four"

}
```

It is possible to do without type casting?

```
 array<String^>^ Finction_Strings_Array=(array<String^>^)Strings_Array;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection does not buy you anything in this case.  The type returned by GetType() is a dynamically generated type that you never declared anywhere in your code.  It derives from `System::Array`.  You need a priori knowledge that the object is actually an array so that you could sensibly index an element.  Given that requirement, it is just simpler to cast to System::Array.  Like this:

```
void Replace_Two(Object^ Strings_Array) {
    Array^ arr = safe_cast<Array^>(Strings_Array);
    arr->SetValue("Four", 2);
}
```

You could add a bunch of code to this, checking the rank of the array to make sure it is a one-dimensional one.  And double-checking that the index you use is not out-of-bounds.  But you don't have to, the CLR will generate a good exception anyway.